# View .bat as plain text from link using Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, iis-6

I need to allow users to click a link to a .bat file on an IIS 6.0 server directory and view that file as plain text. I have set the MIME type for .bat file to "text/plain." This works perfectly in both Chrome and Firefox. The way this works is that I have a button that launches a separate popup browser window to the .bat file. Example is below:

```
onclick=\"window.open(\'\/eemcontrolpanel\/jobs\/" + encodedFileName +"\',\'popUpWindow\',\'height=500,width=400,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=yes\');\">View Script</button>").scrollHeight;
```

As I said, this works in both Chrome and Firefox, but for some reason, IE 8 immediately closes the popup and asks me if I want to Run or Save the file.

Comment: There's a setting in Internet Options | Security | Internet/Intranet Zone, with which you can set, if IE detects the file content basis on MIME type or file content. It's in "Miscellanous" part of the option list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think IE goes by filename extension to detect its an executable file. Maybe you could give it another name by adding a header like:

```
'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="thebat.txt"'
```